# How to securely implement a cross domain authentication system similar to stackexchange

Tags: security, authentication, web

I would like to implement a cross domain authentication system similar to StackExchange. Here is the flow that stackexchange uses:

1. Verify that the user is not authenticated.
2. Make a request to "/users/login/global", the server responds with a token.
3. Make a request to the stackauth.com/auth/global with the previously acquired token (in step 2). The server returns a javascript which is executed when loaded.
4. The javascript makes an other ajax request to the auth server with the token and returns an other token (authToken).
5. The client makes another request to "/users/login" with the authToken. The server returns a session cookie.

Before I try to implement it myself, I would like clarify some steps. How does the authentication server and the current stackexchange are interacting in the backend? What the first and the second token respectively do? Is there any security concerns I should be aware of?

Comment: SE uses [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/).

Comment: My question is more about how to transfer my a session from one domain to the other securely.

Comment: Check out the meta.stackoverflow post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274